# SVG createElementNS 'use' is it possible?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

shortening, I'm using (use) to replicate the square (path) the code is added to the DOM however, only 1px (debug chrome). Is not visible to the sixth block the User!
thank you!
[code in: codepen](http://codepen.io/alexsouzadobrasil/pen/wBJYrg)

```
$(function() {
  $('#svg').css('visibility', 'visible');   
  $('#svg use').css('fill', '#fff');

  function addAnim() {
    var $first = $('#svg use:not(.anim):first');
    $first.attr('class', 'anim').css('fill', '#F15A29');    
    $first.animate({fill : '#F15A29'}, 500);
    setTimeout(function() {
      addAnim();
    }, 100);
  }

  function replicar(){
      var svg = document.getElementById('svg'); 
      var elemento= document.createElementNS('ttp://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
      elemento.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#shape');
      elemento.setAttribute('y', '62');
      elemento.setAttribute('x', '124');
      elemento.setAttribute('fill', '#3D6EB5');
      svg.appendChild(elemento);   


  addAnim();
  replicar(); 
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing an 'h' in this line:

```
var elemento= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
```

Also, xlink attributes need to be added with `setAttributeNS`.

```
elemento.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', '#shape');
```

Comment: You helped me a lot! I'm happy now. very grateful.